# Debian "chrome for testing" package for puppeteer v20?

Tags: debian, puppeteer, chrome-for-testing

I'm currently installing the [chromium package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/chromium) to get the chromium binary needed for [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).  The reason I'm installing it myself, rather than relying on the binary bundled with puppeteer, is because [puppeteer doesn't provide one for arm64](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7740).

But as from [puppeteer v20.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/puppeteer-v20.0.0), they have switched to using "chrome for testing" rather than chromium ([see here for details](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/10054)).  It doesn't seem like there's a "chrome for testing" package, or even a "chrome" package for Debian?

How would I go about installing the relevant binary on Debian?